# Code for putting and removing breakpoint after some time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Code for putting and removing breakpoint after some time in asp.net?

Comment: Need more detail.  A breakpoint in Visual Studio?  Simply causing the debugger to break?  Via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use an if (statement) Debugger.Launch();

Comment: The Debugger only launches at the point when the if statement is true, you can set a bool flag yourself to do so in your code.